# Bitlocker error on Win7 (Domain)

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I have Win7 Ultimate 32-bit running and I am trying to enable Bitlocker on the system drive. The system is running in a Win2003 Domain. I have been successful at enabling Bitlocker on other Win7 systems running in the same domain (mix of 64-bit and 32-bit).

When I use control panel to "Turn On Bitlocker" from a domain admin account I get an error during the system requirements check. "Changes made to your system require that you restart before running Bitlocker Setup." Problem is, I've already restarted, several times, none of which resolved the problem.

I have had Bitlocker running in the past on this system with Windows Vista Ultimate 32-bit so I know the hardware can handle it. I'm not sure what else to try. Any ideas would be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Bitlocker, and reinstalling it?

Answer (score 1):

Is is possible that any of your PCR settings have changed since your initial boot? See http://thelazyadmin.com/blogs/thelazyadmin/archive/2007/05/15/bitlocker-gpo-settings.aspx for instructions on how to check which PCRs are also in use.

I'd also be interested in knowing whether you can run the manage-bde command (from an elevated command prompt) and what it returns for -status and -on.

Comment: I don't have a TPM either BTW. I did find a GPO seems to be stuck. I have another question added to the list regarding this. thanks.